# Converting XML to JSON with variable item size

Tags: java, xml-to-json

For our project , we sometimes get a list of array of pans, sometimes a single pan . 
We are converting the below to json on the fly using the org.json library and consuming in some java application.
    XML :

```
  <item>
  <b type="playlist">Pan1a</b>
  </item>

  <item>
  <b type="clip">Pan2a</b>
  <b type="clip">Pan2b</b>
  </item>

  JSON 

  {
    "item": {
      "b": {
        "-type": "playlist",
        "#text": "Pan1a"
      }
    }
  }


  {
    "item": {
      "b": [
        {
          "-type": "clip",
          "#text": "Pan2a"
        },
        {
          "-type": "clip",
          "#text": "Pan2b"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The issue is , if the item has more than 1 objects the json is giving ArrayList [] , but if the number of objects  =1 then giving single Object and not Array with size 1. As a result we are unable to parse the json at the endpoint as pojo need to be defined first.
What is the best way to make the xml give json as below with size 1 only.

```
  {
   "item": {
     "b": [{
       "-type": "playlist",
       "#text": "Pan1a"
     }]
   }
 }
```

Comment: One way would be converting from XML to POJO and then POJO to JSON before sending to the final application. Another is to write a custom deserialization method which can handle a `List` or single element.

Comment: Another way is to get an XML to JSON converter which lets you pass in an XML schema. The schema defines the structure of the XML.. in this case it would define that `item` needs to be a list

Comment: Can you also send your that does the conversion? It maybe helpful

Comment: public static String convertXMLToJSON(String XMLfile) {
        org.json.JSONObject jsonObj;
        String jsonString = ""; 
 try {
            jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(XMLfile);
            jsonString = jsonObj.toString(1);
            System.out.println(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException je) {

        }
     return jsonString;
    }

Comment: It would be better if you update your question with your code, it would be much more readable. Where this XML class comes from? Is it part of a third party library you're using (e.g. org.json) or a custom made class?